# Order by numeric Advanced Custom Field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I want to order by an [Advanced Custom Field](http://advancedcustomfields.com) numeric field, however I can't seem to get it to work:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'category_name' => 'staff-' . $wp_query->queried_object->post_name,
    'meta_key' => 'scroller_order',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'type' => 'NUMERIC',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

The ACF field is called scroller_order and it only allows numbers but I want to order by whatever the person puts in that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',` instead of simply `'meta_value'`

Check out the [ACF Documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/) too - it's pretty thorough.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this information because it was removed from the documentation:

```
query_posts('cat=222&meta_key=YOUR_ACF&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC');
```